# Canvas is not seting to center of the screen

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap

I have two canvas and two bitmaps, one bitmap is overlaying another when user touch and     move on first bitmap it goes transparent and second bitmap image is shown, till hear every thing is working properly. But when i am trying to move both bitmaps to center of the screen the touch is not detecting correctly, i have to touch above the image at blank screen to make it erasable.

```
package com.example.canvastest;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.AvoidXfermode.Mode;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Bitmap.Config;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.BlurMaskFilter;
import android.graphics.BlurMaskFilter.Blur;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
 import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.graphics.PorterDuff;
import android.graphics.PorterDuffXfermode;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
Canvas c2;
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(new TouchView(this));


}



class TouchView extends View{
Bitmap bgr;
Bitmap overlayDefault;
Bitmap overlay;
Paint pTouch;
int X = -100;
int Y = -100;


public TouchView(Context context) {
    super(context);

    bgr = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.sg);
   // overlayDefault = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.g325);
    overlay = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.g325).copy(Config.ARGB_8888, true);  
    c2 = new Canvas(overlay);

    pTouch = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);         
    pTouch.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.DST_IN)); 
    pTouch.setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    pTouch.setMaskFilter(new BlurMaskFilter(10, Blur.NORMAL));


}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {

    switch (ev.getAction()) {

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {

            X = (int) ev.getX();
            Y = (int) ev.getY();
            invalidate();

            break;
        }

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {

                X = (int) ev.getX();
                Y = (int) ev.getY();
                invalidate();
                break;

        }           

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

            break;

    }
    return true;
}


@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
    super.onDraw(canvas);


    //draw background
    canvas.drawBitmap(bgr, 0, 0, null);
    //copy the default overlay into temporary overlay and punch a hole in it                          
    //c2.drawBitmap(overlayDefault, 0, 0, null); //exclude this line to show all as you draw
    c2.drawCircle(X, Y, 40, pTouch);
    //draw the overlay over the background
    //canvas.drawBitmap(overlay, 0, 0, null);

    Paint new_paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    new_paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP));
    canvas.drawBitmap(overlay, 0,  0, new_paint);

}


}


}
```